# Unlimited interval for CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android

in this below simple code i want to set unlimited interval for CountDownTimer. i can not find any document for this action.

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timerHasStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  rnd = rand.nextInt(1000000000);
        text.setText("" + rnd);
    }
}
```

i want to stop that by click on button to finish.

Comment: What is the end result? Do you want a CountDownTimer that just never finishes but is active? Or do you want to disable the CountDownTimer?

Comment: @Compass never finish

Comment: Why not use a standard [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) then?  `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` allows you to create a timer that lasts forever, and then the onTick can be used in the Task that the fixedRate Timer creates.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the CountDownTimer infinite you can restart it `onFinish` method
like this

```
public void onFinish() {
if (!finishBtnPressed) {
 countDownTimer.start();
} else {
//your logic
}    

}
```

CountDownTimer has a method `cancel()` and you can call it when finish button is clicked (Note that `cancel()` call `onFinish()` so that's why i added the boolean variable `finishBtnPressed`). If you want to have some alternative then look into [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)